# Pyramid setting mako.imports not working

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I'm trying to use the [mako.imports](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/environment.html#mako-import) setting to avoid importing modules in every template file.

Originally I had a module-level block at the top of every template like:

```
<%!
    import logging
%>
```

And I'd like to replace that with a setting in the .ini file:

```
mako.imports = 'import logging'
```

This does not work as the template just throws `NameError: name 'logging' is not defined` when I attempt to use it.

It appears the mako.imports doesn't even get called, since a setting like:

```
mako.imports = 'import SpamAndEggs'
```

doesn't throw an error.

I'm using Pyramid 1.3 and Mako 0.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [pylons-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/pylons-discuss/cOyeUkHRAN8), the syntax is:

```
mako.imports = 
    import logging 
    import some.other.module
```

Import statements separated by line breaks. I think the docs should state this with an example, as "string list" to Python people is rather different.

Thanks to Mike Merickel.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so looking at the Pyramid-generated Mako template code, it just literally outputs what's in that config setting, quotes, brackets and all.

So, the syntax has to be:

`mako.imports = import logging`

with multiple imports as:

`mako.imports = import logging, some.other.module`

and **not** any of these:

```
mako.imports = 'import logging'
mako.imports = ['import logging', 'some.other.module']
mako.imports = import logging, import some.other.module
```

The last throws a `mako.exceptions.SyntaxException` since it's not valid Python, but the first 2 fail silently, doing nothing, since they just output a literal as a line of code.

I didn't infer this from the [documentation](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/environment.html#mako-import) that reads "String list of Python statements, typically individual “import” lines" (but maybe I just didn't understand it correctly).

Thanks to Mike Bayer for his [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mako-discuss/RNUfqX12YHE) on Mako.